# Error launching JabRef under Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: java, 18.10, openjdk

I use JabRef (Version 4.3.1) under Ubuntu, but the last time I tried to launch it, I got this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.jabref.JabRefMain`

I have `java-8-openjdk-amd64` and I think the problem has to do with OpenJFX (see [FAQ](https://help.jabref.org/en/FAQlinux)) and the upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10
(The solution from this question does not work for me:
[JabRef error on launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085502/jabref-error-on-launch))

According to this [post](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2867) "*JabRef explicit requires JDK8 and **openjfx8***".

18.10 comes with `openjfx 11+26-4` (18.04 had version `8u161-b12-1ubuntu2` according to  [ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&searchon=names&keywords=openjfx))

However, I could not figure out how to install `openjfx8`.

**Update**:

I figured out how to install openjfx8 manually (downloading and running the .deb file from [ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&searchon=names&keywords=openjfx)). Before I tried to use `apt`. But I still get the same error.

These are my currently installed versions:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

$ apt-show-versions openjfx
openjfx:amd64/cosmic 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 upgradeable to 11+26-4
openjfx:i386 not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to install Oracle JRE. This way you will have JavaFX inside and no need to install it separately.

Apart from that if you want to continue trying with OpenJDK.
I am not sure if you have 1.8.0_191 (8u191) can use openjfx version 8u161.

By the way your java can be headless because it is written `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)`

Then it does not have part of the GUI libraries. This can be a problem.
You have to install not a headless java.

For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280872/difference-between-openjdk-6-jre-openjdk-6-jre-headless-openjdk-6-jre-lib

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862344/what-is-the-difference-between-openjdk-7-jre-headless-and-openjdk-7-jrejdk/32862422

Good Luck!

Comment: I don't think it's headless, I assume I would have to specifically install `openjdk-8-jre-headless` (I ran `sudo  apt install openjdk-8-jre`)

Comment: I currently use the Oracle JRE and it works, but I would prefer to use OpenJDK